# PHP - substr and date. Why dos if sentence reacte outside the timeframe set?

Tags: php

I have the following if sentence that is activated by a cron tab every halt an hour:

```
if((substr(date('Hi', time()),0,-1) == '065') OR (substr(date('Hi', time()),0,-1) == '070'))
{ send_email() }
```

It sends me an email at 07:05 as it should. However I also recieve an email at 09:05.

Hopefully an idiot error, but please advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, easiest thing first before i look at the code properly ... why dont you just fire the cron at 7:05?

Comment: can I see your crontab line?